# Selenium Webdriver , Can't submit form with captcha

Tags: forms

On some site with Captcha, when completing form fields, it appears that in some cases, the values ​​are not sent when POST the form.

For example with this site  http://www.mmozed.com/forums/index.php, I always get the error

*You did not complete the anti-bot puzzle. Please try again.*

Thank's for your help.

Christian.

Comment: Are you saying you want to bypass the CAPTCHA form? You think if it was that easy, wouldn't the CAPTCHA be kind of useless? It simply isn't possible. Captcha's are not designed to be read by anything other than a human. Regardless, you should disable the CAPTCHA form if it's a site you own. There is not much you can do here.

Comment: Even if I knew the answer to this, I wouldn't tell you. There's no reason for you to want to do this that wouldn't involve spam or some crap like that.

Answer (score 1):

That would be because you aren't supposed to spam websites, and CAPTCHAs are designed to prevent that.